# How can I ensure varioref generates unique labels when the document is split into separate files?

Tags: cross-referencing, varioref

After adding the [varioref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/varioref) package (to generate text like "Figure XX on page YY" from TeX input like `\vref{fig:example}`), I started seeing warnings like

```
LaTeX Warning: Label `1@xvr' multiply defined.
LaTeX Warning: Label `1@vr' multiply defined.
```

My document has chapters stored in separate files: `chapter1.tex`, `chapter2.tex`, etc., which are referenced from the master document using

```
\include{Chapter1/chapter1}
\include{Chapter2/chapter2}
...
```

I traced the problem to the fact that `varioref` generates its own `xvr` and `vr` labels by concatenating a counter with `@xvr` and with `@vr`. It seems that this counter is reset for each file. For example, in my document, `chapter5.aux` contains

```
\newlabel{1@xvr}{{}{181}{Review of ...}{subsection.5.3.2}{}}
\newlabel{1@vr}{{}{181}{Review of ...}{subsection.5.3.2}{}}
```

and `chapter6.aux` contains

```
\newlabel{1@xvr}{{}{198}{Introduction to ...}{section.6.1}{}}
\newlabel{1@vr}{{}{198}{Introduction to ...}{section.6.1}{}}
```

Clearly, the labels generated by `varioref` are duplicates across chapters, though they are unique within a chapter. I wish to fix the problem because I do not have confidence that, when referencing a label in a different chapter (say, `\vref{sec:Introduction to ...}` from `chapter5.tex` in the example above), the page reference will be correct in all cases.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

**Update**: *It seems that that `varioref` does not always work well with forked versions of [CUED thesis template](https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template).* YMMV!

Comment: Labels must be unique across the document; `varioref` has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Thank you @egreg The issue is that `varioref` generates its own labels according to the algorithm above. These auto-generated labels are the only labels that LaTeX claims are not unique in the document. I was hoping there might be some way to influence how `varioref` generates its labels.

Comment: What are the related main `\label` commands?

Comment: In `chapter5.tex` the example is  `\label{subsec:Review of ...}` which LaTeX converts to `\newlabel{subsec:Review of ...}{{5.3.2}{181}{Review of ...}{subsection.5.3.2}{}}` in chapter5.aux. Compare with the first block of `\newlabel` statements generated by `varioref` in the question above.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: I did two `\include` commands, but the counter is not reset.

Comment: Worst case you can erase all the old aux files and run it twice.

Comment: Hi @egreg. Like you, I have tried a minimal example and confirm your finding: the counter was not reset with each `\include`. Therefore, I expect there is some clash between `varioref` and one or more of the packages/customisations in the thesis template I forked from <https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template>, which is the template I was using when the problem showed up. I don't have time to follow the process of elimination needed to isolate the culprit so, unless there is a simple workaround, I will revert to using plain `\ref` references. Thanks very much for your help, @egreg!

Comment: Hi @JohnKormylo. Thanks for the suggestion, but it did not work on this occasion.

Comment: Does it work if you use \input instead of \include? Or is the counter reset by \chapter?

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer. I tried replacing `\include` with `\input` but that did not help. You are correct - with some package configurations, `\chapter` seems to reset the `vrcnt` counter - see @FrankMittelbach answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`varioref` uses a saved version of the `\label` command to generate such labels in the `.aux` file:

```
\def\vref@label#1{\@bsphack
  \protected@write\@auxout{}%
         {\string\newlabel{#1}{{}{\thepage}}}%
  \@esphack}
```

This is more or less identical to the definition of `\label` in `latex.ltx` except that it doesn't pass `\@currentlabel` to `\newlabel`.

The real reason for having this saved version is that `babel` and `amsmath` redefine `\label` in a way unsuitable for varioref's purpose here.

However, the mods done in these template seem to result in the LaTeX counter `vrcnt` being reset per include (or perhaps generally per chapter?) and so you get double labels.

In varioref it is defined simply by

```
\newcounter{vrcnt}
```

so it should not be reset ever. Perhaps the mod changes `\newcounter`?

So my suggestions would be

1. to try loading varioref as early as possible perhaps even with `\RequirePackage` before the class or if that doesn't work
2. explicitly set it yourself per chapter file, e.g.,

   ```
   \setcounter{vrcnt}{1000}
   ```

   incrementing by 1000 for each chapter - it is a manual workaround but I guess it would work.
3. or you might try changing `\vref@label` to include `\thechapter` in the label name or what ever is needed to make the labels unique again, e.g.

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \def\vref@label#1{\@bsphack
     \protected@write\@auxout{}%
            {\string\newlabel{\thechapter:#1}{{}{\thepage}}}%
     \@esphack}
   \makeatother
   ```

   in the preamble.

Ultimately the people having done the class file would need to look there as this is a bit weird that the counter is reset for no good reason.

Comment: Thanks very much @FrankMittelbach. *I followed suggestion 1 and it solved my problem*. I had added the `varioref` package late in the list of such packages and moved it to the front of the list as you suggested. If I later run into difficulties, I can always fall back on suggestions 2 and 3; I believe they should work too!